# CSS not working after moving to subfolder

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I moved my Wordpress site from Root directory to Subdirectory; the dashboard is working normally but the front css is not working correctly, the navigation menu doesn't show at all and the rest is shown in plain html format.

I have changed the urls through permalinks and from cpanel (including removing the old .htaccess file and creating a new one) as well hoping this would solve the front appearance problem but sadly it didn't.

I'll appreciate if you help me solve this and make the site appear normal again.

Comment: change css file path so that it properly works. most properly calls from header or head file

Answer (score 1):

I'm mostly sure that you never changed the url of the  tag that is calling your css, before you made the directory move, it might be something like "your-website.com/css/style.css", but after that, you need to modify it to be like "website.com/subdirectory/css/style.css" or instead of using absolute paths, you can do de same with relative paths, like "./css/style.css"

Comment: I know changing urls is important, but all i knew was changing it through wordpress settings and from cpanel. I didn't know i should change it in files as well. Now, I checked the header.php but it's all functions, even in the <link rel> tag, it's just functions, no path like what you wrote. what do you advice?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `src` in the link tag where you linked the css to the html.